# Can I place a multipart form inside another form? File uploading

Tags: forms, file-upload

My customer currently has a single form of text inputs and select boxes etc.  They now would like to have a field where the user can upload a file( they would like this placed pretty much right in the middle of the other form fields).

I was just going to use a multipart form to do the upload however this would place a form inside of a form.  From what I've read having a form inside a form is not recommended and only works on some browsers. Is this true? What would my best option for this situation?

Thanks -Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.   Answer: No, this is a very bad Idea.